# javascript prototype class, this in jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, prototype, this

I made a javascript prototype class.

Inside a method I create an jquery click.
But inside this click I want to execute my build function.

When I try to execute a prototype function inside a jquery click it fails because jquery uses this for something else.

I tried some different things, but I couldnt get it working.

```
Game.prototype.clicks = function(){
    $('.flip').click(function(){

        if(cardsPlayed.length < 2) //minder dan 2 kaarten gespeeld
        {
            $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
            cardsPlayed.push($(this).find('.card').attr('arrayKey'));

            console.log(cardsPlayed[cardsPlayed.length - 1]);

            console.log(playingCards[cardsPlayed[cardsPlayed.length - 1]][0]);

            if(cardsPlayed.length == 2)// two cards played
            {
                if(playingCards[cardsPlayed[0]][0] == playingCards[cardsPlayed[1]][0])
                { // same cards played
                    console.log('zelfde kaarten');
                    playingCards[cardsPlayed[0]][0] = 0; //hide card one
                    playingCards[cardsPlayed[1]][0] = 0; //hide card two
                    //rebuild the playfield
                    this.build(); //error here
                }
                else
                {
                    //differend cards
                }

            }
        }

        return false;
    }).bind(this);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Where is the code?

Comment: editted my post with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to have `this` reference the clicked `.flip` element in `$(this).find('.card')` *as well as* the `Game` object in `this.build()`. `this` can't have a dual personality, so one of those references needs to change.

The simplest solution, as already suggested by Licson, is to keep a variable pointing to the `Game` object in the scope of the `click` handler. Then, just use `this` inside the handler for the clicked element (as usual in a jQuery handler) and use `self` for the `Game` object.

```
Game.prototype.clicks = function() {
    // Keep a reference to the Game in the scope
    var self = this;

    $('.flip').click(function() {
        if(cardsPlayed.length < 2) //minder dan 2 kaarten gespeeld
        {
            // Use this to refer to the clicked element
            $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
            // Stuff goes here...
            // Use self to refer to the Game object
            self.build();
        }
    }); // Note: no bind, we let jQuery bind this to the clicked element
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
function class(){
    var self = this;
    this.build = function(){};
    $('#element').click(function(){
        self.build();
    });
};
```

Comment: I've tried something simular but unfortunately I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, in modern browsers you can simply use `bind`:

```
function MyClass() {
  this.foo = 'foo';
  $('selector').each(function() {
    alert(this.foo); //=> 'foo'
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Otherwise just cache `this` in a variable, typically `self` and use that where necessary.

Comment: didn't notice any different when added bind(this), sorry

Comment: @JasperFioole: Look closely at my code and then yours. `bind` is for functions.

Comment: I've tried it on some different locations in my code But it didn't show any differents. I added my code in my question. Could u tell me where to place it? thx

Comment: @JasperFioole: `}.bind(this)) != }).bind(this)`. See what I mean? You need to run `bind` on the function not on the `click` jQuery method.

Comment: I know what your mean, ive tried that, this gives an error on: console.log(playingCards[cardsPlayed[cardsPlayed.length - 1]][0]); -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, this probably happens because I use the this variant of jquery as well : cardsPlayed.push($(this).find('.card').attr('arrayKey'));

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to have `this` be the jQuery object in `$(this).find('.card')` *as well as* the `Game` object in `this.build()`. Even `.bind()` can't help you with that.